# Cant retrieve company record from EDGAR platform

Tags: r, finance, edgar

Im trying to retrieve company information from EDGAR platform with following code:

```
library(edgar)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)


tesla <- getFilingsHTML(
  cik.no = 0001318605,
  form.type = '10-K',
  filing.year = 2017,
  quarter = c(1,2,3,4)
 )
```

However, I get the following error:

```
No filing information found for given CIK(s) and Form Type in the mentioned year(s)/quarter(s).
```

I have checked the CIK code as well as the website www.sec.gov and everything looks to be OK.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kaspersky, when enabled, interferes with edgar and the getFilingsHTML function

> Downloading Master Indexes from SEC server for 2017 ... curl: (35)
>   schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error
>   (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation
>   for the certificate. curl: (35) schannel: next
>   InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The
>   revocation function was unable to check revocation for the
>   certificate. curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext
>   failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was
>   unable to check revocation for the certificate. curl: (35) schannel:
>   next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) -
>   The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the
>   certificate. No filing information found for given CIK(s) and Form
>   Type in the mentioned year(s)/quarter(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you read `help(getFillingsHTML)`:

```
getFilingsHTML {edgar}
Get HTML view of EDGAR filings
Description
getFilingsHTML retrieves complete EDGAR filings and store them in HTML format for view.

Usage
getFilingsHTML(cik.no, form.type, filing.year, quarter)
Arguments
cik.no  vector of CIK number of firms in integer format. Suppress leading zeroes from CIKs. Keep cik.no = 'ALL' if needs to download for all CIKs.

form.type   character vector containing form type to be downloaded. form.type = 'ALL' if need to download all forms.

filing.year vector of four digit numeric year

quarter vector of one digit quarter integer number. By deault, it is kept as c(1 ,2, 3, 4).
```

For `cik.no` it states to suppress leading zeros.

Thus:

```
getFilingsHTML(cik.no = "1318605",
   form.type = '10-K',
   filing.year = 2017)
#Downloading fillings. Please wait... 
#  #|========================================================================================================================| 100%
#Scrapping full EDGAR and converting to HTML...
#  #|========================================================================================================================| 100%
#HTML filings are stored in 'Edgar filings_HTML view' directory.      cik company.name form.type date.filed     accession.number
#1 1318605  Tesla  Inc       10-K 2017-03-01 0001564590-17-003118
```

Comment: thanks. i just tried  with your advise and get exactly the same message. could it be something on my side?

Comment: You get exactly the same message that I got in my code? If so, you should find a copy of form 10-K in a folder in your working directory `getwd()`. [See](https://i.imgur.com/3ETUT2G.png)?

Comment: i didnt say it correctly. i still get the error messge
`No filing information found for given CIK(s) and Form Type in the mentioned year(s)/quarter(s).`

Comment: Perhaps you could try restarting R and trying the code again?

Comment: did it. also removed package and reinstalled. also restarted pc and still get nothing. like you, a friend just did it and she got your result :(